# innerHTML problem in FF, Chrome. IE is fine

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, innerhtml

i have a page where inputs are loaded dynamically on button press.
When the button is pressed, I add the source code to the innerHTML of the container element.

So if you press it it once it will contain  . 
if you press it again, it will add a second one, with name 'inp-2'.

The problem is that if you add one input, you fill it in with some text, then you press the add button again, the inserted text will gone, because - at least i think so - it keeps the original innerHTML, which does not contain the inserted text. This is happening in FF, Chrome. in IE it is working fine, because the innerHTML of the IE is updated by the user's interactivity; if you fill in an input then you view the source code, then you will see your text is in the input's value attribute, not like in FF or Chrome.

What do you suggest, how can this be solved in the most quick and efficient way? Keep in mind that I have simplified the code to a single input, but for each press of the button, a huge source code is added to the innerHTML (1 table containing trs, tds, about 9 inputs and text). thanks

Comment: Code please. Is it wrapped inside a table? Also, which doctype?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using .innerHTML, instead of DOM methods that will actually append nodes, you will need to add "change" event handlers to those inputs. The browser is not required to synchronize the `value` attribute and the `value` property of the `<input/>`, but your event handler can do that in a cross-browser way.

Try something like this. The innerHTML should be updated each time the attribute is updated.

```
node.innerHTML += '<input name="inp-#" value="starting_value" onchange="this.setAttribute(\'value\',this.value);" />';
```